# can't change AD password on ubuntu with sssd

Tags: ubuntu, active-directory, sssd

I've configured sssd on an Ubuntu 18.04 server in aws to join an AD domain.
I've already managed to sucessfully login using an active directory account, so i'm assuming all AD services are correctly configured in this machine.

The issue appears when i try to change the password (using passwd).

```
lucas.camilo@DOMAIN@HOSTNAME:~$ passwd
Current Password:
New password:
Retype new password:
Password change failed. Server message: Please make sure the password meets the complexity constraints.
passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
passwd: password unchanged
```

As for the error message, i've already checked the complexity requirements and it's not that (i'm the one that set those up), and i've also found that [it's a generic error message](https://askubuntu.com/questions/981570/active-directory-users-unable-to-change-passwords-sssd).
After setting debug_level to 10 (using `sudo sss_debuglevel 10`), i tried again, got the same message on output, and i got this on  `sudo cat /var/log/sssd/krb5_child.log`

(... pasting the last 4 lines)

```
(Tue Jul  7 23:12:21 2020) [[sssd[krb5_child[2410]]]] [changepw_child] (0x0020): krb5_change_password failed [4][Password change rejected].
(Tue Jul  7 23:12:21 2020) [[sssd[krb5_child[2410]]]] [k5c_send_data] (0x0200): Received error code 1432158228
(Tue Jul  7 23:12:21 2020) [[sssd[krb5_child[2410]]]] [pack_response_packet] (0x2000): response packet size: [83]
(Tue Jul  7 23:12:21 2020) [[sssd[krb5_child[2410]]]] [k5c_send_data] (0x4000): Response sent.
(Tue Jul  7 23:12:21 2020) [[sssd[krb5_child[2410]]]] [main] (0x0400): krb5_child completed successfully
```

I'm not finding much using that error code (1432158228), and i'm faily new to using AD on linux.
Am i doing this wrong? Is there any better way of changing AD passwords from linux?

Thanks!

Comment: Ran into this issue on my end. In AD, the "User cannot change password" was checked.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Weirdly enough, it took two reboots (and a couple of hours of doing nothing) to get it working.
Hopefully won't happen again.

Answer (score -1):

In case someone gets this issue when attempting a password change to an AD server : the default group policy has a "Minimum Password Age" which will prevent you from changing the password for 24 hours after user creation / previous password change.

Solution is to change the GPO to zero days and do a gpupdate on domain controller - or wait for 24 hours.

To validate this issue you can use debug mode as shown above and lookup error code 1432158228