# Joined linux host to AD server using realmd. Unable to change ad user passwords from the command line

Tags: linux, authentication, active-directory, sssd

Have a fairly simple setup of one AD server with various linux hosts. We attached the linux hosts to our domain by using:

```
realm discover domain.example.com
realm join domain.example.com -U user.adm
```

Our /etc/sssd/sssd.conf looks like:

```
[sssd]
domains = domain.example.com
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam

[domain/domain.example.com]
ad_domain = domain.example.com
krb5_realm = DOMAIN.EXAMPLE.COM
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-samba
cache_credentials = True
id_provider = ad
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
default_shell = /bin/bash
ldap_id_mapping = True
use_fully_qualified_names = false
fallback_homedir = /home/%u@%d
access_provider = simple
simple_allow_groups = linuxaccess@domain.example.com
```

From here we can login as AD users that are a part of the linuxaccess group. I attempted to reset a password but get:

```
[username.lin@hostname ~] passwd
Current Password:
New password:
Retype new password:
Password change failed. Server message: Access denied
passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
```

/var/log/secure shows:

```
Oct 12 14:39:48 computer passwd: pam_unix(passwd:chauthtok): user "username.lin" does not exist in /etc/passwd
Oct 12 14:40:01 computer passwd: pam_unix(passwd:chauthtok): user "username.lin" does not exist in /etc/passwd
Oct 12 14:40:01 computer passwd: pam_sss(passwd:chauthtok): Password change failed for user username.lin: 20 (Authentication token manipulation error)
```

Thoughts on why changing passwords do not appear to be supported or what the misconfiguration could be? Guessing something in pam.d but not confident.

Comment: This is a linux admin question, not programming, so out of scope for SO.  Try admin sites, you have a better chance of getting an answer.

Comment: @Nic3500 ill search for others then. My other on the admin page has gotten 0 views/up votes but no answers in 12 days which is why I opted for this one hoping sssd/pam.d was a better suite for here.

Comment: @Govind Sharma. Will do. Should be able to validate today/tomorrow and accept

Comment: @RahulKumarShaw-MT My apologies, this is still on my list to circle back in the lab and work to resolve. Should get to it this week and will accept. Thanks!

Comment: Hello IT-User,If you have tested in your lab and it helps for you, upvote and accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your scenario and I am also getting the same error when attempting password change for AD users.

the default group policy has a "Minimum Password Age" which will prevent you from changing the password for 24 hours after user creation / previous password change.

[image]

Solution is to change the GPO to zero days and do a gpupdate on domain controller - or wait for 24 hours.

The GPO security settings on your Active Directory server were most likely default or possibly customized by the AD Administrator.

**Note: Minimum password age:**
Set this value to 1 day. Microsoft recommends to not set this to 0, because it would allow immediate password changes. Users can change the password 24 times the same day and get back to the old password.

Reference: https://www.pcwdld.com/domain-password-policy-how-to-configure#wbounce-modal

[can't change AD password on ubuntu with sssd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62785700/cant-change-ad-password-on-ubuntu-with-sssd)